# Variable from Separate Function Cannot Print in Main

Tags: java

```
public class practiceclock{

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int x = 5;
    addTonum(x);
    System.out.println(gby);
  }
  public static void addTonum(int gby) {
    gby = gby + 1;
  }
}
```

Why doesn't this print out 6? I'm trying to print out the integer gby from my "addTonum" function. I know it's pretty basic.

Comment: This doesn't even compile!

Comment: That would explain it not printing out 6.

Comment: Why should it print 6? You're passing a primitive and incrementing it. You're not passing an object reference.

Comment: Make gby static or return it back after increment into System.out.println

Comment: Thx guys. I got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In java, when you pass a variable as an argument into a method, you are passing a copy of it, not the original instance. To fix this, you can either make the variable global, or you can have the method return the integer.

Also, use

```
gby +=1;
```

As a shortcut.

Comment: Unless it is an object.